# LWC changes updates Aura, BUT Aura changes does not updates LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, lightning-message-channel

I have a scenario where two components an Aura and a LWC were included via Object Record Type. They are placed according to the image below.

[image]

I'm facing a problem. All the interactions done in LWC gets the related data in Aura updated. **But**, when some data in aura are updated, the related data in LWC are not update. That is, **LWC does not know it**. It is not refreshed. It is done **only when I refresh the entire page** so that an @wire function (methodController) is called. See below.

```
import methodController from '@salesforce/apex/Controller.methodController';

    @wire(methodController, { 
        recordId: '$recordId' 
    })
    handle({error, data}) 
    {
      // business logic
    }
```

methodController is called only once, when the page is loaded.

How to make it to be called all the time that some actions in Aura are done?

Comment: is your method cached ? have you looked into using refreshApex?

Comment: Yes. It has annotation, I'm using refresh method too. But the problem is when I click on component inside aura, this action doesn't update the LWC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

It is in this post. This design worked in the scenario that I have posted

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000DOUnQAO

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
const FIELDS=['Account.Id'];

export default class ShowToast extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    account;
    lastModifiedDate;
    
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
    wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
        if (error) {
           console.log('error occured');
        } else if (data) {
            this.account = data;
            let modifiedDate = this.account.lastModifiedDate;
            if(!this.lastModifiedDate) {
                this.lastModifiedDate = this.account.lastModifiedDate;
            }
            if (modifiedDate != this.lastModifiedDate) {
                this.showNotification();
            }
        }
    }

    showNotification() {
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Success',
            message: 'Account Updated',
            variant: 'success'
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}
```